# Laravel 5.4 belongsToMany relationship returns empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In Laravel 5.4 I'am trying to set up a Many To Many Relation. but the belongsToMany returns empty! Here's my migrations and models.

**botusers** Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('botusers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('t_id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('mobile');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**candidates** Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('candidates', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('token');
        $table->string('degree');
        $table->integer('age');
        $table->text('desc');
        $table->string('photo_url');
        $table->string('cv_url');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Third table, **botuser_candidate** Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('botuser_candidate', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('botuser_id');
        $table->integer('candidate_id');
    });
}
```

and the `votes()` method in **Botuser** Model:

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Candidate::class)->get();
}
```

When I fire the `votes()` method returns an empty array. and I also tested bellow method too,

```
public function votes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Candidate::class,'botuser_candidate','botuser_id','candidate_id')->get();
}
```

What I missed here? What should I do?

**Edit:**
I also added the foreign keys to the relation but the result is still same!

Comment: Do you have data in database though? In `botuser_candidate` table. Also, unrelated, you're not using foreign keys judging by your migrations.

Comment: 2 notes: remove the get() from the relationships and add foreign keys to add constraints

Comment: @devk Of Course! I have data! In an other project I do the same thing and it was ok!

Comment: I would second @Christophvh 's suggestions, but otherwise everything you pasted looks correct. So I don't think the problem is with your code. Perhaps including the contents of the three database tables (or at least one record from each table) would help to prove that the data you're working with is valid. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the query that using are using to fetch the data.

Comment: @oseintow In tinker I use bellows to test my model: `$c=new App\Candidate;  $c->votes()` and the result is  `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#671
     all: [],
   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you remove the get() method on the belongsToMany

Then query the database with

```
$c=new App\Candidate; 
$c->with('votes')->get()
```

if you still want to use `$c->votes()` then you would have to do some changes to your functions. Lets use scope to achieve it.

```
public function candidates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Candidate::class,'botuser_candidate','botuser_id','candidate_id');
}

public function scopeVotes($query)
{
   return $query->with("candidates")->get();
}
```

Then now we can call `$v->votes()` and it should return all your record.

Calling get() directly on belongsToMany method will return empty array.

Comment: You're a real savior! :)

Comment: I'm so sorry about that but it doesn't give me what I need! this give me all the Candidates and I couldn't fetch for exaple number of users who voted!

Comment: You question never statement that you want specific candidate.

Comment: You can edit you question and add the candidate that you want. Then i will update the answer

Comment: In an other project I used just like what I written on question and it works for me! but in this case I don't know what is wrong. I mean when I fired for example this code: `$c = new Botuser; $c->votes();` it gave a list of Candidates to me that are in relation width Botuser!